# Insert block Custom form builder into PHTML?

Tags: magento-1.9

i want add custom form builer in my landing page `homepage.phtml`

```
{{block type="formbuilder/frontend_form" name="frontend_form" 
form_id="1"
template="formbuilder/form.phtml"}}
```

is posible add block into phtml file?
this is an option...

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('contacts/form.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

but i need include `form_id="1"` into the code?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get **form_id="1"** to `formbuilder/form.phtml`,you can use
`$this->getFormId();` .

Also,**Is possible add block into phtml**,*`yes possible`*

Comment: but the numer of id where i can put the id? inside of ( 1 )?